# Windows 10 freezes on accessing WLAN functions

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, freeze, windows-10, pci-express

I can't use my wlan adapter.
Whenever I access any functions of wlan the computer freezes/hangs/crashes.   Nothing happens then. The only thing I can do, is a hard-reboot (reset-button).

Those parts are affected:
- Networkbutton in tray
- Info-center > Connect

I use Windows Pro Version 10.0.10240
My wlan adapter is a [TP-Link TL-WN851ND](http://www.tp-link.com.de/products/details/?model=TL-WN851ND#spec).
The device-id of this wlan adapter is:
PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_002D&SUBSYS_0300168C&REV_01

The driver for this product is installed by windows on boot (startup), without asking me for a source. Furthermore there is no explicit compatibility given for this product and windows 10. But Windows 8.1 is supported. And it also works, as WLAN networks are shown (but when hovering them it freezes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution on my own:

- Insert the driver disk for the specific wlan adapter
- Open in Explorer the disc content (For example D:)
- Right-click the file that is your setup (usually autorun.exe)
- Properties > Troubleshoot compatibility > Troubleshoot program
- Tick only "The program worked in earlier versions of Windows but won’t install or run now"
- Click next
- Select the Windows Version that worked for this software before (for me it was windows 7)
- Click next
- Test the settings
- Install the software
- Should be fine now